# PHP generate content on linked page using data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I started building a site and found useful info here, so hope you can help me out on this as I'm stuck.

My site is live here: http://ivolschi.co.uk/Tentativa1/. I have articles each with a small picture that will link to a new page displaying a video. I'm generating the data in the articles from the database using PHP. When you click on a image you can see it links to a new page example: http://ivolschi.co.uk/Tentativa1/image_id=2 where '2' is the image id.

The PHP part that takes the data from the database and adds the image id on the link is:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM image ORDER BY image_id DESC';                                     mysql_select_db('10gag');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval ) {
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {                                      
    echo "
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 left'>
        <div class='row article'>
            <div class='post-content'>
                <a href='image_id={$row['image_id']}'target='SELECT video.movie_url FROM video inner join image on video.video_id= image.image_i'>
                    <img src={$row['image_source']} width= '160' height= '100'>
                </a>
            </div>
            <p>{$row['image_text']}</p>
        </div>
    </div>      
    ";
}
?>
```

I need to display on the ivolschi.co.uk/Tentativa1/'image_id' the video(movie_url) that matches the image_id in the database.

The database is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `image_name` text NOT NULL,
  `image_source` text NOT NULL,
  `image_text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
  `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `movie_title` text NOT NULL,
  `movie_url` text NOT NULL,
  `votes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`),
  KEY `image_image_id_fk` (`image_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `video`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `image_image_id_fk` 
   FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `image` (`image_id`);`
```

Can you please point me at the PHP code I need to use to accomplish this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If every article has a picture, you can do the initial `SELECT INNER JOIN` with `video`. In the `a` `href` target, verify that you have the absolute or relative path to the database.

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM image INNER JOIN video ON image.image_id = video.image_id ORDER BY image_id DESC';                                     
mysql_select_db('10gag');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval ) {
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {                                      
    echo "
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 left'>
        <div class='row article'>
            <div class='post-content'>
                <a href='{$row['movie_url']}'>
                    <img src={$row['image_source']} width= '160' height= '100'>
                </a>
            </div>
            <p>{$row['image_text']}</p>
        </div>
    </div>      
    ";
}
?>
```